# How to connect OpenVPN automatically on BOOT using openvpn3-autoload?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, client

I am trying to make a OpenVPN solution of my Ubuntu 20.04 VM. I found that there are two clients which can connect to OpenVPN server (running in pfSense), one is network-manager-gnome and the other is openvpn3.

For the network-manager-gnome, I can import the .ovpn file but I cannot connect to the OpenVPN server using the profile. Then I try the openvpn3, which require command-line to make it work, and it is able to connect to the OpenVPN server. I also find that the openvpn3-autoload can be used to connect to OpenVPN server by a single command.

However, I want to make an automatically solution which the desktop can connect to the OpenVPN server on startup without any manually action. I would like to know if there is a solution to do this job.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.

Although I had read and follow the guide (https://openvpn.net/openvpn-3-linux-and-auth-user-pass/), I forget to run `systemctl daemon-reload`
Without this command, the systemd don't know there is a new service file

First, we need to follow the guide to make a directory, copy the client.ovpn files and make the openvpn_profile.autoload files for the openvpn3-autoload service

Remind to edit the privilege

```
chmod 600 $HOME/.openvpn3/autoload/openvpn_profile.ovpn && chmod 600 $HOME/.openvpn3/autoload/openvpn_profile.autoload
```

Then copy the service file

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn3-autoload.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn3-autoload.service
```

and edit the service file to add the user and change the default configuration directory

```
sudo vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn3-autoload.service
```

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN 3 Linux configuration auto loader and starter
After=network.target dbus.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=myusername
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn3-autoload --directory /home/myusername/.openvpn3/autoload
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload the daemon again, enable and start the service

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable openvpn3-autoload.service
systemctl start openvpn3-autoload.service
```

Reboot the VM and confirm the result